# NIC teaming LACP runner not getting IP

Tags: 16.04, networking, 18.04, dhcp

I followed Redhat teaming configuration guide to configure NIC teaming on Ubuntu, except LACP, others work as expected.

I tried both `teamd` with JSON config file and `nmcli` methods, both can create LACP team interface, but when I tried to configure IP address, neither DHCP nor static work.

`$ ip a` shows `No-carrier` and `state is DOWN` for team interface.

Anyone ever had that working on Ubuntu?

[Update] Here is my config file (from `/usr/share/doc/libteam-utils/examples/lacp_1.conf`):

```
{
        "device":               "team0",
                "runner": {
                        "name": "lacp",
                        "active": true,
                        "fast_rate": true,
                        "tx_hash": ["eth", "ipv4", "ipv6"]
                },
                "link_watch":           {"name": "ethtool"},
                "ports":                {"eth0": {}, "eth1": {}}
}
```

I don't have the network switch at home, I will post output of ip address, ip route, and ip link that Mr Shunz suggested after I go back to office.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1084905/edit) your question and post the configurations you tried? Also the output of `ip address`, `ip route` and `ip link` would be useful.

Comment: [Command output](https://ibb.co/m02aO0)